# Checking for transactions in Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

In Sequelize, you can:

- Manually pass a transaction as a second argument to each query
- Or automatically pass transactions to all queries using CLS.

I'd like to go with the manual option, but I'd like to change the default model behavior so that queries will throw an error if no transaction is provided. An optional `noTransaction` argument will allow you to bypass the transaction check.

i.e.

```
myModel.update({newValue: true}); // throws Error "No transaction specified"
myModel.update({newValue: true}, {transaction}); // OK
myModel.update({newValue: true}, {noTransaction: true); // OK
```

What's the best way to go about updating the default behavior of model methods in Sequelize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is simple as Sequelize supports adding a hook to all models:

```
sequelize.addHook('beforeCreate', checkForTransaction);
sequelize.addHook('beforeUpdate', checkForTransaction);
sequelize.addHook('beforeDestroy', checkForTransaction);

function checkForTransaction (data, options) {
  if (!options.transaction && !options.noTransaction) {
    throw new Error('Transaction is required');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think the best solution is not to create a transaction manually at all. But to let decorators do the work for you.

```
function start() {
    try {
      const transaction = sequelize.transaction();

      // allowing me to pass it to multiple functions.
      foo(transaction);
      bar(transaction);

      transaction.commit();
    } catch(err) {
      transaction.rollback();
      throw err;
    }
}
```

Becomes as short as

```
@Transactional
function start(@Tx transaction) {
  foo(transaction);
  bar(transaction);
}
```

The transaction parameter becomes optional, and will be initialized automatically whenever necessary. It basically allows all methods to be executed individually or as part of a bigger transaction. And you never have to write code for it.

This requires a [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zb-sequelize):

```
npm install zb-sequelize
```

You do have to give it access to your `sequelize` instance.

```
import { initSequelizeResolver } from 'zb-sequelize';
initSequelizeResolver((args) => sequelize);
```